# Multivariable chain rule heat equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

here's the problem:
the equation
$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}$ should be transformed using $\xi=\frac{x}{\delta(t)}$ and $T(x,t)=\phi(t)F(\xi,t)$. The result of the transformation should be $\phi\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial \xi^2}=\delta\left( \delta \phi_t F+\delta \phi\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}-\xi\delta_t\phi \frac{\partial F}{\partial \xi}\right)$.

Can you please explain how to get this result?

Comment: could you please specify what transformation did you appiled, and provide more context of your problem?

Comment: That result doesn't seem quite correct.  Are you certain as to its correctness?

Comment: Well i think it is called landau transformation. However, it is some kind of a boundary immobilization technique. It is from http://www.staff.ul.ie/mitchells/Mitchell_NHT11.pdf equation 30. Oh I just saw, that there was a little typo in the question. Noe it should be correct.